# Proof of existence of Pul e Sirat in Akhirah

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, uloom-al-quran, akhirah

I've heard that if we don't accept that ***Pul e Sirat*** doesn't exist in Akhirah , it doesn't affect our Eman . Is this true ? Moreover, is there any proof of existence of Pul e Sirat from Quran or Hadith ?

Answer (score 1):

It is obligatory to believe in the bridge(Sirat) over the hellfire. Anyone who rejects it exits the fold of Islam.

> Abu Saʿīd Al-Khudri narrated that Allāh’s Messenger(ﷺ) said, “Every
> nation shall follow whatever they worshipped. Only this nation will
> remain along with its hypocrites. Then the **Bridge (As-Sirāt)** will
> be erected over the Hellfire, and I will be the first to cross it and
> the intercession will be permitted. The people will say, ‘O Allāh,
> Save us! Save us!’” It was said, “O Allāh’s Messenger, what is the
> Bridge?” He replied, “A void into which a person is likely to slip.
> Upon it there are claws, clamps and hooks like the thorns found in
> Najd called Saʿdān. The believers would then pass over it in the blink
> of an eye, like lightning, like wind, like a bird, like the finest
> horses and camels. Some will escape and be safe, some will be
> lacerated and let go, and some will be pushed into the fire of Hell.”
> (Muslim, no. 183)

In another Hadith

> Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him,
> said, “I will be the first to cross the **bridge** over Hell. The
> supplication of the Messengers on that day will be: O Allah, keep us
> safe! O Allah, keep us safe! There will be hooks on the sides like the
> thorns of al-Sa’dan, except their enormity is only known to Allah.
> People will be seized by them according to their deeds. Among them are
> those who are ruined by their deeds. Among them are those who are cut
> into pieces and later saved, until Allah has finished judging between
> His servants and He intends to take out of the Hellfire whomever He
> wills to take out. For whomever testified there is no God but Allah,
> the angels will be ordered to take them out and they will be known by
> their trace marks of prostration. Allah has forbidden the Hellfire
> from consuming any children of Adam with traces of prostration. They
> will be taken out after they had been burned, then dipped into a water
> called the water of life. They will spring forth like seeds on a
> streaming river.” Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6573, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 182

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, there is authentic evidence the Sirat is true. As Muslims, we must believe everything, without exception, from the book of Allah or the speech of His Messanger (peace and blessings be upon him).